# Serving Apostrophe-CMS S3 assets & attachments as HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, apostrophe-cms

I"m using **Amazon S3** to serve my static assets and user uploads in **apostrophe-cms**. My site loads with https, but all my assets are loading as http.

I have a **cloudfront** distribution at the static subdomain of my site, but I'm not sure how I can configure **apostrophe-cms** to use this for locating my assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this by specifying the following for your `apostrophe-attachments` config:

```
// in ./lib/modules/apostrophe-attachments/index.js
module.exports = {
  uploadfs: {
    https: true,
    cdn: {
      enabled: true,
      url: 'https://assets.example.com'
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yup! Thanks a lot!! Just wondering, is there anywhere you found this besides the source code? The docs for apostrophe are a little sparse lol.

Comment: @ZachB. Yeah I picked it up a couple days earlier when cross-reading the docs and remembered it when I read your question. I find the How To section in the docs to be really helpful, it's a lot of repeating patterns you'll want to use, explanations and use cases etc. Also there are some behind the scenes modules which power a lot of the Apostrophe Modules with their own documentation. For example the apostrophe-attachments module is powered by [uploadfs](https://github.com/punkave/uploadfs) which has quite helpful docs in the readme. Happy developing!

Comment: Hmm, is there any reason why I can't set this config in my app.js and instead have to do it in the index.js file?

Comment: You can do either way. Apostrophe will looks for the /lib/modules/apostrophe-attachments/index.js file and load it automatically. I prefer to put the module configuration in a dedicated file to keep the app.js file small and lean. It's more of a preference where to put it.

Comment: This should be included in the documentation for Apostrophe:
https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud-with-heroku.html